# Manually copy plugin in netbeans

Tags: plugins, netbeans, netbeans-7

Is it somehow possible to manually copy the plugin from one version to the next? Basically I want to copy a plugin from Netbeans 7.3 beta 2 to Netbeans 7.3 (final release).

The plugin in question is JIRA.

Alos if someone has any other idea how to install it (can I download the plugin for previous version manually for example)

I have tried few things but non of them worked.

- copy the folders under extra in netbeans dir
- tried to download it from http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/updates/7.3/uc/beta2/certified/modules/extra/ but it kept requesting additional plugins that I couldnt find. It didnt resolve dependencies by itself

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beta versions of NetBeans have a 'Plugins in Development' update center set up, which is omitted from Release build (in order to by default only provide plugins that are known to work). To add Plugins in Development update center follow these steps:

1. Open `Plugins` dialog, go to `Settings` tab.
2. Click on `Add`
3. Enter `Plugins in development` as a name (or whatever you choose)
4. Enter http://deadlock.netbeans.org/hudson/job/nbms-and-javadoc/lastStableBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz as a URL
5. Click OK
6. Install your JIRA plugin

Another update centre you might want to set up is the one associated with [Community Plug-In Portal](http://plugins.netbeans.org/) and it's URL is: http://plugins.netbeans.org/nbpluginportal/files/nbms/pluginportal-update-center.xml

Comment: sadly the plugin seems to be broken I am getting some classnotfound exception when i try to publish my changes

Comment: You should contact plugin developers for support. It seems the plugin is developed by JIRA team.